# Form is empty, so it gives me a validation error even before I submit

Tags: php

Im really new to php, so hear me out.
I made a simple page with a form that validates whether the data you sent was ok to send, but it gives me a validation error I made even before I enter anything. Heres the code:

```
 <html>
 <body>
         <form action="first.php" method="post">
            Username:<input type="text" name="username"><br />
            Password:<input type="password" name="password"><br />
            <input type="submit" name="submit"><br />
         </form>
 <?php
     $errors = array();
     $username = $_POST['username'];
     $password = $_POST['password'];
     $errors = array();
     if(!isset($username) || empty($username)){
        $errors = "Empty username<br />";
      }
     if ($username > 10){
        $errors['username'] = "Username out of range<br />";
     }
     if (!empty($errors)){
         echo "Error<br />";
         print_r ($errors);
     }

 ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your PHP code into a `if()` condition:

```
if( isset($_POST['submit']) )
{
    $errors = array();
    (...)
}
```

Without this, your code is executed even if form is not submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 <html>
 <body>
        <form action="first.php" method="post">
             Username:<input type="text" name="username"><br />
             Password:<input type="password" name="password"><br />
             <input type="submit" name="submit"><br />
        </form>
        <?php
           if(isset($_POST['submit']))
           {
              $errors = array();
              $username = $_POST['username'];
              $password = $_POST['password'];
              $errors = array();
           if(!isset($username) || empty($username)){
              $errors = "Empty username<br />";
            }
           if ($username > 10){
              $errors['username'] = "Username out of range<br />";
           }
           if (!empty($errors)){
                echo "Error<br />";
                print_r ($errors);
            }
          }
        ?>
</body>
</html>
```